# Fast overlap save method

Tags: overlap-save

If `x[n]= (some values)`, `h[n]=(some values)`.  Now suppose length of `h[n]` is a multiple of two. Being specific say it has length of four.. Then `M=4`, Then what should be value of `L` and value of `N` to satisfy `N=M+L-1`..

E.g. which i tried solving is.

```
x[n]={7,6,4,5,2,4,5,2,3}
h[n]={1,2,3,1}
```

Taking `N=8` i got `L=5`.

```
x1[n]={0,0,0,7,6,4,5,2}
x2[n]={4,5,2,4,5,2,3,0} (extra zero to make length=N)
```

Now while solving I found to lose some of values using save method.

Comment: without any other condition specified, other than L>0, the choice is arbitrary and your question, honesty makes no sense. please consider modifying it so it does

Comment: Actually i tooked N=8 and then L=5 ..i found to loose some of values. Instead of 12 (which is length of convolution) values i got just 10. Contradictory i found correct answer for same values using overlap add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for overlap-save, (sometimes called *"overlap-scrap"*) when you (circularly) convolve `h` with `x1`. you scrap the first 3 output values of `y1` and keep the last 5 values.  when you (circularly) convolve `h` with `x2`, again you scrap the first 3 values of `y2` and keep the last 5 values.

with

```
x[n]={7,6,4,5,2,4,5,2,3}
h[n]={1,2,3,1}
```

it should be

```
x1[n]={0,0,0,7,6,4,5,2}
x2[n]={4,5,2,4,5,2,3,0}
```

remember that in convolution, `h[n]` gets turned around to be `h[-n]` (`h[0]` remains in the same position but the other values are extended to the left).  only when `h[0]` is aligned with `x1[3]` will you get a legitimate value for `y1[3]`.  and notice, because you (necessarily) delayed `x[n]` by 3 samples with that initial zero-padding, the output will also be delayed by the same amount.

Comment: I have got that 10 values... But sir,  the Problem is that total length of result should be ( length of x[n]+length of [n] -1).  Thats makes 9+4-1=13 ... Its getting  wrong result

Comment: y[n]={7,20,37 ,38 ,30 ,27 ,24 ,26 ,26 ,17 ,11 ,3} using normal calculations..  But while solving am not getting last two digits i.e. y[10] and y[11]